# Can anybody please tell me how to develop i phone app on windows computer?

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, mobile

Is there any ide for develop iphone app on windows computer ?

I want to start to develop a **i phone** app on windows xp.
But i do not have mac book. I want to develop it on my windows computer, is there any application which will help me to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

To develop iOS app you need mac OS X for sure, now you can have an apple machine or you can install Mac OS in non apple machine using VM, for that you can use virtual box installed in windows and then install Mac OS X on VM, there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

you can install Hackintosh in your windows to develop iphone app

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one of the available tools for cross platform development, but I seriously advise against that. You should go native - the result will be much better.

Assuming you choose to go native (which, again, I highly recommend), and decide to develop your app specifically for iOS devices, you have to do this on a mac. The reason you don't want to mess with hackintosh and its counterparts (regardless of their running slowly, hard to maintain, etc) is that if you develop an app not on a mac device, and Apple finds out, you're in big trouble and will probably end up banned from the App Store. Assuming your app is built with the goal of ending up as a successful one, this is a chance that you shouldn't be willing to take.